# Codeigniter Add Glyphicon to Form Button

Tags: php, html, arrays, codeigniter, glyphicons

Using Codeigniter 3 I would like to display a glyphicon on my form submit button.

My code so far is;

```
$data = array(
    'type'      => 'submit',
    'content'   => 'Add Book',
    'class'     => 'btn btn-sm btn-labeled btn-success'
    );
echo form_button($data);
```

This produces the following html;

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-labeled btn-success">Add Book</button>
```

However I would like to produce this html;

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-labeled btn-success"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span> Add Book</button>
```

I have tried the following;

```
echo form_button('<span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>', $data);
```

This produces an error *Array to string conversion*.

I have also read the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html), but can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try this echo form_button( $data,'<span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>');

Comment: $data = array(
    'type'      => 'submit',
    'content'   => '<span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Add Book',
    'class'     => 'btn btn-sm btn-labeled btn-success'
    );

echo form_button($data);

Comment: try my second comment it will work as  you expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the span like this

```
$data = array(
'type'      => 'submit',
'content'   => '<span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>Add Book',
'class'     => 'btn btn-sm btn-labeled btn-success'
);

echo form_button($data);
```